# Could the parity-ethereum client incorporate doing range proofs in the ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I want to be able to prove that I have stored a number that is in the range of a minimum and maximum value, (a range proof) without revealing the number, and put the value into the ethereum blockchain, so that it can be verified by anyone.

There's a project in the Rust language called bulletproof located here: https://github.com/dalek-cryptography/bulletproofs , could it be added to the client to do this?

How difficult would it be to add this feature? I'm an experienced Java programmer, and I'd rather work in Java, but I guess I can learn Rust!